# Include minified JavaScript files in war

Tags: javascript, scala, sbt, xsbt-web-plugin

I'm using sbt-js 0.3 to build a Scalatra web project. I've included the following lines in `build.sbt`.

```
(webappResources in Compile) <+= (resourceManaged in Compile)

(resourceGenerators in Compile) <+= (JsKeys.js in Compile)

(compile in Compile) <<= compile in Compile dependsOn (JsKeys.js in Compile)
```

When I run `compile` the minified files do get generated in the `target/scala_2.9.1` folder. But I can't get these files in the war when I use `package` (from xsbt-web-plugin) or `assembly` (from sbt-assembly). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [xsbt-web-plugin](https://github.com/siasia/xsbt-web-plugin/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/siasia/WarPlugin.scala) it seems by default to copy from sourceDirectory/webapp and assemble everything in target/webapp.

I think you need to massage your WAR as shown [here](https://github.com/siasia/xsbt-web-plugin/wiki/Massage-WAR) (except do a copy not a delete) or re-configure to include your minified JS in the webappResources setting.